# Ruby on Rails Przelewy24 payment system implementation, undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment

I'm trying to implement Przelewy24 Payment System in my app via this gem: https://github.com/jcieslar/przelewy24_payment

But I have problem with payment verify, precisely I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in PaymentsController#comeback
undefined method `force_encoding' for nil:NilClass
```

Probably this is the problem with receiving data from Przelewy24 because when I am getting no method error the request parameters and response headers is none.
This is my config file:

```
Przelewy24Payment.setup do |config|
  config.merchant_id = 'XXXXX'
  config.pos_id = 'XXXXX'
  config.crc_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  config.language = 'pl'
  config.currency = 'PLN'
  config.country = 'PL'
  config.mode = :development
  config.url_status = '/kam'
  config.url_return = '/kam'
  config.hostname = {
      :development => "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
      :production => "mydomain.pl",
      :staging => "staging.domain"
  }
end
```

And my routes for **/kam**

```
get '/kam' => 'payments#comeback'
```

I can't directly set url_status and url_return to  **'/payments/comeback'** which is url for show action in my controller, because then I am getting error

```
Couldn't find Payment with 'id'=comeback
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this problem, please help me.

Comment: Could you maybe show the code from your controller? I'm particularly interested in the line that throws the error.

Comment: Of course, I just posted this below

Comment: Hmm, I assume that your routes aren't setup properly. Apparently `/payments/:id` is the route that brings you to the show action (as is the Rails default). Then when you call `/payments/comeback` rails interprets the `comeback` as the id parameter, tries finding a Payment with `comeback` as the id and fails.

Comment: I know this because I set the route in this way: 
`get '/kam' => 'payments#comeback'`
I'm calling /kam which leads to comeback action in payments controller. Maybe the problem is in calling comeback action separately from show action which provides data from payment button, so then the response from Przelewy24 doesn't include any params.  But how can I provide handling comeback action in /payments/comeback if as you say rails tries finding a Payment with id comeback.

Answer (score 0):

This is my **Payments Controller**

```
  class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
          include Przelewy24PaymentController


  def index
    @payments = Payment.all
  end



  def show

    @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])


        @data = { :session_id =>  @payment.session_id,
              :description => @payment.porada.title,
              :amount => @payment.porada.cena,
              :email => @payment.user.email,
              :country => 'PL',
              # adding this params, you overwrite your config settings so this param is optional
              :merchant_id => ‚XXXXX’,
              :pos_id => ‚XXXXX’,
              :api_version => '3.2',
              :crc_key => ‚XXXXXXXXXXX’,
              :currency => 'PLN',
              :country => 'PL',
              # :url_return => url_return,
              # :url_status => url_status,

              # other optional params
              # :language => pl/en/de/es/it
              # :method => method,
              # :client => 'Adam Nowak',
              # :address => 'Powstancow 22/2',
              # :zipcode => '53-456',
              # :city => 'Wroclaw',
              # :phone => '481321132123',
              # :time_limit => INT,
              # :wait_for_result => INT,
              # :channel => INT,
              # :shipping => INT,
              # :transfer_label => STRING(20)
              # :encoding => ISO-8859-2/UTF-8/Windows-1250

            }

  end



  def new
      @payment = Payment.new(:porada_id => params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
        @payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
    @payment.session_id = Przelewy24Payment.friendly_token[0,20] 
    @payment_porada = @payment.porada
        @user = current_user
        @payment.user_id = current_user.id
        @payment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @payment.update(payment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @payment, notice: 'Payment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @payment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @payment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @payment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to payments_url, notice: 'Payment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def payment_success(payment_params)
    # payment_params returns hash with:
    # p24_merchant_id
    # p24_pos_id
    # p24_session_id
    # p24_order_id
    # p24_amount
    # p24_currency
    # p24_method
    # p24_sign
    # p24_karta
    # payment_id
    # e.g
    # payment = Payment.find_by_session_id(payment_params[:p24_session_id])
  end

  # after error payment this method will be trigger
  # so you can do whatever you want
  def payment_error(payment_params, code, description)
    # payment_params returns hash with:
    # p24_merchant_id
    # p24_pos_id
    # p24_session_id
    # p24_order_id
    # p24_amount
    # p24_currency
    # p24_method
    # p24_sign
    # p24_karta
    # payment_id
    #
    # code return error code
    # description return error description
  end

  # method to setup params to verify it final verifyciation
  # so you can do whatever you want
  def payment_verify(response_params)
    # e.g:
    # you must return hash with amount which was save in your db and your crc_key
    payment = Payment::Payment.where(session_id: response_params['p24_session_id']).first
    if payment
      { amount: payment.amount, crc_key: Przelewy24Payment.crc_key }
    else
      {}
    end
  end







  private




    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_payment
      @payment = Payment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def payment_params
      params.require(:payment).permit(:amount, :porada_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

And this is the **comeback** action which is built-in in przelewy24_payment gem.

```
def comeback
      result = przelewy24_verify(params,request.remote_ip)
      if result.error == "0"
        payment_success(params)
      else
        payment_error(params, result.error, result.errorMessage)
      end
    end`
```

The data was sending from from the show view by the

```
<%= payment_button(@data) %>
```